# Pausing HTML 5 video in Safari 5.1.7 for Windows

Tags: windows, html, video, safari, video.js

I'm trying to pause every instance of an HTML 5 `<video>` tag on a page after an event is fired using:

```
jQuery("video").each (function() { this.pause(); })
```

Works in all browsers EXCEPT Safari for Windows 5.1.7, which throws:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.pause()')

Why do Safari throws this exception and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

edit:

so, given you are using video.js, maybe something like this?

```
jQuery("video").each (function() { 
  _V_($(this).id).pause(); //make sure all your video tags have an id attribute
});
```

https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/docs/api.md

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick for Google Chrome now.  I should have mentioned I'm trying to use video.js

Comment: Installing Quicktime solved the issue.  Media playback is not supported natively on Windows Safari 5.1.7.  Thanks for your help.